# how to include php file in laravel ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5, ckeditor

Hey I would like to include a php file into my larvel blog page using, ckeditor. I have 2 problems when I add in  tags they are commented out and html  tags are just filtered out in the database. When I just add the <?php code or script in the database directly to the body in database the code is still there but the <?php code still does not parse/execute but it will show up in the blog page.

I can execute php from my database as long as I am the using php eval() function, but the eval is not parsing in ckeditor source code. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.
Im using larvel 5.7 and ckeditor 4+

Here are the images
db image

[inserted php in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWmN3.png)

blog post img
[ckeditor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBUhW.png)

ck source img
[view ckeditor source code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVD2D.png)

For reference here are pics of php eval() without using larvel ckeditor db img

[working php eval reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIlIE.png)

output img
[output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bRI9.png)

code to output/ reference for working example
'''

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM e.g.";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    $row1 = $row['middle_name']; //would be changed to row['body'] for larvel blog

    eval($row1);
    
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

'''

Comment: CKEditor is a WYSIWYG text editor. It's the wrong tool if you want people to be able to paste in PHP that's going to get executed on the server. (Note that letting people do that has huge potential for intentional or accidental misuse, and can easily lead to server corruption.)

Comment: yea ik thats why only I can create blog/posts.

Answer (score -1):

nvm I found a bypass.

you can use an html  onload="";

```
<div id="topBar"> <a href ="#" onload="load_home()"> HOME </a> </div>
<div id ="content"> </div>
<script>


function load_home() {
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="sometthing.html" ></object>';
</script>
}
```

You can also use an <iframe src="" in the ckeditor or add directly to the database to add php code on that file

```
<iframe onload="function()" src="...eg page you want to load"></iframe>
```